# Migration Error In laravel

Tags: migration, laravel

[Exception]
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'lotus.product_types' doesn't exist (SQL: alter table `product_types` add `id` int unsig
  ned not null auto_increment primary key, add `name` varchar(100) not null, add `company_id` varchar(255) not null, add `created_at` timestamp defa
  ult 0 not null, add `updated_at` timestamp default 0 not null, add `deleted_at` timestamp null) (Bindings: array (
  ))

How to solve

Comment: Could you include the code from the original product_types migration as well as your altering migration?

Comment: public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('product_types', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name', 255);
   $table->string('company_ids', 255);            
            
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }